# TextBlob Spelling correction takes lot of time

Tags: nlp

I am trying to perform spelling correction using TextBlob. Following is the sample code

```
enter code here
%%time

import textblob
from textblob import TextBlob
import progressbar
from time import sleep
bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=10000, widgets=[progressbar.Bar('=', '[', ']'), ' ', 
progressbar.Percentage()])
bar.start()
index = 0
for text in corpus['text_final']:
    bar.update(index)
    #print(str(index))
    corpus['text_final'][index] = TextBlob(text).correct()
    index = index + 1
    sleep(0.01)
    bar.finish()
```

My corpus includes 2500 statements of average 25 words, and it has already taken 1.5 hours and it still 46% complete.

Does anyone have any suggestions to do it faster? Please suggest